# PHP HTML table set to beside column after x column

Tags: php

I have html table with PHP function to show it.

```
$todayDate = date("m/d/Y");
$tomorrowDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime('tomorrow'));

$start = $todayDate.' 08:00:00';
$end = $tomorrowDate.' 07:59:59';

$time = strtotime($start);
$timeStop = strtotime($end);
$no = 1;

while($time<$timeStop)
{
    <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>

    <td>
        <?php
        $date1 = date('H:i', $time);
        echo date('H:i', $time);
        $time = strtotime('+60 minutes', $time);
        echo ' - ' . date('H:i', $time) . '<br/>';
        $date2 = date('H:i', $time);
        ?>
    </td>

    <td>0</td>

    <td>
        <?php
        $today = strtoupper(date("d-M-Y"));

        $qHourlyOutput = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTALS FROM MEP_TBL_OUTPUT_DETAILS WHERE MODELID_FK = '" . $dData['MODELID'] . "' AND SHIFT = 'Morning' AND TO_CHAR(RUNNING_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') BETWEEN '$today $date1' AND '$today $date2'
        ");
        oci_execute($qHourlyOutput);
        $dHourlyOutput = oci_fetch_array($qHourlyOutput);

        echo $dHourlyOutput['TOTALS'];
        ?>
    </td>

    <td>
        a
    </td>

    <tr>

    <?php
    $no++;
}
```

And the display like this:

[image]

Now I need, column number more than 13 go to beside table.

Like below
[image]

My question, how can I set specific column go to beside?
How to do that?